# Time dependent cloudwatch monitoring is possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to monitor my EC2 instance state (running or stop) and set alarm in case, EC2 stop. My EC2 will run only from 9AM to 6PM. Can i accomplish above through cloudwatch and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudWatch Event [Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) rule:

> You can create rules that self-trigger on an automated schedule in CloudWatch Events using cron or rate expressions. All scheduled events use UTC time zone and the minimum precision for schedules is 1 minute.

For example.

One rule would start the instance at 9 AM from MON-FRY

```
0 9 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

[image]

Other rule would stop the instance

```
0 18 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

[image]

For starting the instance you would need to create a **lambda function**. For stopping you call StopInstance API directly using CloudWatch trigger:

[image]